# How to config vscode cmd+p to open files in a new tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever i'm searching for a file in project using cmd+p and opening the file hitting enter its opens. If i search again using cmd+p then the file is opened in the same tab. How to open files in different tabs.

VSCODE - Version 1.6.1 (1.6.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because by default the file first opens in preview mode. As long as you don't edit the first file or double click its tab, the tab will be reused.

If this behaviour is not you thing, you can disable it with the following setting:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false
```

If you want to disable preview mode global (as in: disable it when you click a file from the side pane), there's:

```
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```